# java: How to visualize a Family Tree

Tags: java, tree, visualize

I would like to visualize a Family Tree and save it as an image (byte[]).

The Family Tree is based on a simple model:

```
public class Person {

  private List<Person> children = new ArrayList<Person>();
  private Person partner;
  private Person mother;
  private Person father;

  private final String fullName;
}
```

So far I tried using graphstream and jung. With both frameworks I was able to generate the image, except the position of the nodes are not like they should be in a family tree.

I could write a "Family Tree layout manager" myself, but I'm afraid this is a difficult and error prone process.

Does someone has some advise how to tackle this problem?

Comment: define the modela s a graph and use a deepFirst search algorithm....

Comment: i think i'd just do it myself. But how long that takes strongly depends on how experienced you are. Sadly I don't know any framework that would help you though.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing the "Family Tree layout manager" myself and using jgraph library as the framework.

Comment: explain your answer more so that others could benefit from